# How to generate a self-signed SSL certificate for MS SQL server 2008 R2 using OpenSSL?

Tags: sql-server, ssl, certificate

Using OpenSSL, I'd like to generate a self-signed certificate for usage with Microsoft SQL server 2008 R2. This might be unusual, but I'd like to learn what's going on behind the scenes.

I have several problems:

1) The certificate, after having it installed into the trusted root certificates of the local computer, is not listed in MSSC utility.

2) Therefore, I have forcibly added it by changing the registry as described in several posts. After having done so, the SQL server service didn't start any more. The event log shows

> Unable to load user-specified certificate [Cert Hash(sha1)
>   "350F3D0D987525361CE4CC5E6D72274228C5AF5B"]. The server will not
>   accept a connection. You should verify that the certificate is
>   correctly installed. See "Configuring Certificate for Use by SSL" in
>   Books Online.

followed by other error messages which are undoubtedly caused by that first one.

I am nearly sure that the certificate I generated does not fulfill SQL server's requirements. However, for the life of me, I can't figure out what is missing. This leads to the third problem:

3) Many posts out there recommend the tool CheckSQLssl.exe to examine the certificate and to debug issues. However, I can't find that tool anywhere (not on my SQL server, no download available, even Microsoft doesn't seem to know about it).

These are the commands I am using to generate the certificate:

```
openssl genrsa -out key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key key.pem -out csr.pem -subj /CN=server.example.com
openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 36500 -key key.pem -in csr.pem -out cert.pem
openssl x509 -extfile /etc/ssl/pp-openssl.cnf -sha256 -days 36500 -signkey key.pem -in cert.pem -out ext.pem
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey key.pem -in ext.pem
```

So I generate the key and a CSR which contains the server's FQDN as common name (lines 1 and 2). Then I sign the CSR and generate a self-signed X509 certificate (line 3). Then I add the EKU for Server Authentication (see below) (line 4) to the certificate and finally convert it into PFX format (line 5).

pp-openssl.cnf just contains one line to add the correct EKU:

```
extendedKeyUsage=critical,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1
```

When examining that PFX certificate on the server, it seems that it should meet the requirements:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>certutil -dump -v cert.pfx |find "EXC"
    KeySpec = 1 -- AT_KEYEXCHANGE
    Algorithm Class: 0xa000(5) ALG_CLASS_KEY_EXCHANGE
```

and (only relevant snippet of the output)

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop>certutil -dump -v cert.pfx
    2.5.29.37: Flags = 1(Critical), Length = c
    Enhanced Key Usage
        Server Authentication (1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1)
```

I have read that the EKU and AT_KEYEXCHANGE are important requirements; both are obviously met.

What else could be missing? I'll provide the complete output of `certutil -dump -v` if it helps.

Answer (score 5):

I managed to generate a self-signed certificate that works for encryption of connections to MS SQL Server by using the New-SelfSignedCertificate command for PowerShell.

Example:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -Type SSLServerAuthentication -Subject "CN=$env:COMPUTERNAME" -DnsName "$env:COMPUTERNAME",'localhost.' -KeyAlgorithm "RSA" -KeyLength 2048 -Hash "SHA256" -TextExtension "2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1" -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddMonths(36) -KeySpec KeyExchange -Provider "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider"
```

Running it:

```
C:\mssql>notepad create-ss.ps1

C:\mssql>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\mssql> .\create-ss.ps1


   PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\MY

Thumbprint                                Subject
----------                                -------
14151D156A16557AAA67A4C9465631520CC18626  CN=WIN-9U7N81SI03H
```

[image: Certificate details]

Use of the certificate:

[image]

Giving access to the certificate private key is required as well.

Find the account used to run MS SQL Server:

[image: Find SQLSERVER Service Logon As]

Now from Management Console, Certificates Add-on, Select Manage Private Keys

[image: MMC / Certificates / / All Tasks / Manage Private Keys]

Add the user running MS SQL

[image: Add the user running MS SQL]

Restart MS SQL Server and you should be done.

Comment: Great answer. But... the CommonName (CN) MUST match the Server Name - which it will in your script due to the use of `$env:COMPUTERNAME` but this will error on a client connecting to the server via IP or domain name e.g sql.contoso.co.uk with the certificate installed: `The target principal name is incorrect.`. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: According to someone "Using a DNS name in the Common Name field is deprecated by both the IETF and the CA/Browser forums. Put your DNS names in the Subject Alt Names (SAN). There can be multiple SANs. " https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23523456/how-to-give-a-multiline-certificate-name-cn-for-a-certificate-generated-using

Comment: How do I know which key generated the certificate?

Comment: @rafaelmaldonado not trivial... it seems you have to export it by right-clicking on it from the microsoft management console -> https://www.digicert.com/blog/where-is-your-private-key#:~:text=Windows%20(IIS),-On%20Windows%20servers&text=Open%20Microsoft%20Management%20Console%20(MMC,and%20follow%20the%20guided%20wizard.

Comment: Giving the SQL service account `read` access on the private key was the critical step. Thanks.